# error loading faster_rcnn models into Opencv

Tags: opencv, tensorflow

I followed exactly every step from TensorFlow Object Detection API and trained the faster_rcnn_resnet50 model. Then I referenced link:Wiki to generate the pbtxt file for cv2 read net.

When I ran the model using opencv, it gave no error most of the time and this error sometimes:

> cv2.error: OpenCV(3.4.3)
>   C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\dnn\src\tensorflow\tf_importer.cpp:495:
>   error: (-2:Unspecified error) Input layer not found:
>   CropAndResize/Reshape/shape in function
>   'cv::dnn::experimental_dnn_34_v7::anonymous-namespace'::TFImporter::connect'

I tried the optimized tool and re-generated the pbtxt file, but still experienced the same.

Any suggestions to make the model work? Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you trying to load the .pbtxt file or the .pb file. .pbtxt contains your labels and .pb is the saved model graph.

Comment: @ShubhamJaiswal Hi, I was trying to load both as required by the opencv `readnetfromtensorflow`. The pb file was extracted from the `export_inference_graph.py` and pbtxt file was extracted from `tf_text_graph_faster_rcnn.py`.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: `export_inference_graph.py` is from tensorflow object detection api and `tf_text_graph_faster_rcnn.py` is from opencv [wiki](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/wiki/TensorFlow-Object-Detection-API)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got answer from @dkurt at https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/13050

Wish that can help if you are experiencing the same problem